# box-sizing not getting applied

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create a navigation bar and I've set a padding to it, but due to this padding, my contents are getting outside the limits of the page, and the box-sizing seems not to be applied.

```
.med-navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15rem;
    box-shadow: atomicItemStyle.$boxShadow;
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    box-sizing: inherit;

    &__brandName {
        font-size: 3rem;
        font-weight: 900;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a file that specifies that the box-sizing can't be used?

Comment: @ThomasTromp nope

Comment: apparently it's overwritten by another css rule which has a higher specifity

Comment: @Johannes yes, that was it. Thanks!